# Grails, Can not run WAR-file

Tags: grails, war

When I try running my WAR-file I'll get this:

```
$ java -Dgrails.env=prod -jar build/libs/MyWar-0.45.war
Error: Could not find or load main class  build.libs.MyWar-0.45.war
```

Have these versions:

```
grailsVersion=3.3.3
gormVersion=6.1.6.RELEASE
gradleWrapperVersion=3.5
jdk1.8.0_161
```

It worked on grails 3.3.0.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try `cd build/libs` then run the jar from there instead of the base of your source project.

Comment: Normally my way, as I tried above, works but now I installed windows on a new disk and copied the project from the old disk and upgraded from grails-3.3.0 to grails -3.3.3 it doesn't and not the way you described either. I may need to change something in my project but I have no idea what.

Comment: Have you tried a clean? Also did you copy over caches and repositories to your home directory? e.g. .m2 .gradle and .grails, not saying you should but the project may expect something to be there & may not run without it, sometimes better to start from scratch and check project out from version control on new machine, also does the project run from the or command line using run-app?

Comment: Have you forgotten to include `-jar` in your command?

Comment: Well, I can see now that I forgot it in my question. I don't know how I could miss that because I had it when I run it. But it didn't help when I was running in PowerShell. But removing "-Dgrails.env=prod" from the command line helped when running in PS but I could keep the complete command when running in the classic command window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, it seems, is that the new version of windows10 (1709) doesn't have the command prompt visible in the start-menu. Instead, there is PowerShell and "java -Dgrails.env=prod" doesn't work in PS. It worked when I removed "-Dgrails.env=prod" from the command.
But when I tried RUN-cmd to get the old command window then the complete command worked.
So it seems to be some problem with this command using PowerShell.

This solved my problem but if anyone could explain what's wrong or how you could make it work with PowerShell it would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `java -Dgrails.env=prod build/libs/MyWar-0.45.war` you probably want `java -Dgrails.env=prod -jar build/libs/MyWar-0.45.war`.

Comment: By default your `.war` file will have been built in prod mode so unless you have something unusual in your build that would alter that, `-Dgrails.env=prod` would be superfluous.

Comment: Yes, I realized that when I made it work in the PowerShell by removing the option "-Dgrails.env=prod" as I got the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
grails "-Dgrails.env=prod" run-app
```

Powershell only recognizes the `-Dgrails.env=prod` command if it's quoted.

I successfully ran this command from a `PS terminal` within `IntelliJ IDEA` and from Windows `Powershell`.